# Implement Column Level Filter in Slick Grid Grouping

Tags: jquery, slickgrid

I want to implement column level filtering in Slick Grid Grouping table.
Please find the jsfiddle for grouping using slickgrid.
I want to insert a text box on each column so that when we search for any value the results should be filtered on the particular grouping and not in the whole table.

```
$(function () {

var groupItemMetadataProvider = new  Slick.Data.GroupItemMetadataProvider();

dataView = new Slick.Data.DataView({
groupItemMetadataProvider: groupItemMetadataProvider,
inlineFilters: true
});

//
var columns = makeGridColumns(ReportData.cols);

grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", dataView, columns, options);

// register the group item metadata provider to add expand/collapse group handlers
grid.registerPlugin(groupItemMetadataProvider);


// wire up model events to drive the grid
dataView.onRowCountChanged.subscribe(function (e, args) {
grid.updateRowCount();
grid.render();
});

dataView.onRowsChanged.subscribe(function (e, args) {
grid.invalidateRows(args.rows);
grid.render();
});



// initialize the model after all the events have been hooked up
dataView.beginUpdate();

dataView.setItems(ReportData.data);

groupBy();

dataView.endUpdate();

 })

http://jsfiddle.net/Tdha8/101/
```

Answer (score 1):

hmm, have you checked the example on git?

http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-header-row.html